# Checking if an identifier exists

Tags: java, automated-tests, sap-gui, silktest

In our Silk4J test environment, we use a naming convention in order to conveniently get access to windows. E.g. I can do

```
SapWindow pt61 = sap.performTransaction("PT61");
```

to perform the PT61 transaction in SAP and it'll return a window that has the identifier `wndPT61` in a Silk4J Object Map.

Sometimes it happens that the window has not been mapped yet. In this case Silk4J causes a `RuntimeException`. Unfortunately, `RuntimeException` is used all over the place, i.e. it's not specific.

Is there a way to check the Object Maps for the existence of an identifer, so that I could detect the missing identifier and throw a more specific (custom) exception explaining what to do?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
if (!desktop.isValidIdentifier("wndPT61")) {
    throw new Exception("According to our naming convention ... etc.");
}
```

I have tried:

- I have had a look at all methods of `Desktop`, but IMHO no such method exists. The `exists()`  method already throws the `RuntimeException`.
- I have had a look at all methods of `Agent`, but IMHO no such method exists.
- I don't think such a method should be available at some other class, since desktop and agent are the highest level where a search can be done.
- Of course I can catch the `RuntimeException` (that's what I do at the moment), but it's not very reliable (since such an exception could have other causes) and I don't want to rely on the exception message.